# Jquery slide show stopped working

Tags: jquery

Recently I tried to include a banner link at the end of my slide show and now even if i remove the banner, the ss doesn't work. Can someone please tell me where i went wrong. Here is the code from the entire page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Tom Brydelsky Contemporary Art</title>
<META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="encaustic, inkjet, digital, prints, archival, art, fine-    art, landscape, abstract, artist, gallery">
<META NAME="description" CONTENT="Mixed media encaustic paintings by Tom Brydelsky, who combines encaustic painting and digital technlogies in new compositions">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<LINK rel="shortcut icon" href="/http://www.tombrydelsky.com/favicon.ico">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.tombrydelsky.com/tswtabs.css" />

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.border {
border: thin solid #666666;
}
.slideshow { height: 521px; width: 900px; }
-->
</style>
<link href="css/name.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="art/splash/ArchitecturalDigest2.jpg"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="art/splash/luxe2.jpg"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="art/splash/NYSpaces2.jpg"
var image4=new Image()
image4.src="art/splash/Stheby'sAtlanta2.jpg"
var image5=new Image()
image5.src="art/splash/sunormoonhome.jpg"
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
});
});
</script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/B1D671CF-E532-4481-99AA-  19F420D90332/netdefender/hui/ndhui.css' /><!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/B1D671CF-E532-4481-99AA-19F420D90332/netdefender/hui/ndhui_ie7.css'   /><![endif]-->

</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" topmargin="0">
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="50%">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle"><table width="940" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td width="940">
  <table width="940" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="middle">
    <tr>
      <td width="940" valign="top"  bgcolor="ffffff"><div align="left"><img src="name.jpg" width="710" height="60">
            </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" bordercolor="#ffffff" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <div id="tswcsstabs" align="right">
          <ul>
            <li><font color="#999999"><a href="news.html">news</a></font></li>
            <li><font color="#999999"><a href="art/artindex1.html">artwork</a></font>    </li>
            <!--<li><font color="#999999"><a href="prints/prints.html">prints</a>   </font></li>-->
            <li><font color="#999999"><a href="art/installed.html">installations</a></font></li>
            <li><font color="#999999"><a href="resume.html">exhibitions</a></font></li>
            <li><font color="#999999"><a href="about.html">about</a></font></li>
            <li><font color="#999999"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></font></li>
            <li><font color="#cc7a00">home</font></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" bordercolor="#ffffff" bgcolor="#ffffff"><a href="art/installed.html"><img src="art/splash/newsplash.jpg" width="900" height="500" border="0"></a>
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'></script>
          <div class="slideshow"><img src="art/splash/ArchitecturalDigest2.jpg" width="900" height="500" /><img src="art/splash/luxe2.jpg" width="900" height="500" /><img src="art/splash/NYSpaces2.jpg" width="900" height="500" /><img src="art/splash/Atlanta2.jpg" width="900" height="500" /><img src="art/splash/sunormoonhome.jpg" width="900" height="500" /><img src="art/splash/atlamtaresidence.jpg" width="900" height="500" /><img src= "art/splash/contemporary-living-room.jpg" width='900' height='500' /></div>
    </tr>
     <tr>
   <div align="center"> 
  <img src="art/images/spacer.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0"><br>
     <img src="images2/inmotionbanner3.jpg" width="900" height="100" border="0"></a>       
   </div>
   </div>
    </tr>
  </table>       
    </tr>

  </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</tr>
</table>
<!-- Start of StatCounter Code for Dreamweaver -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc_project=671400; 
var sc_invisible=0; 
var sc_security="01bacc7f"; 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js"></script>
<noscript><div class="statcounter"><a title="hit counter
for tumblr" href="http://statcounter.com/tumblr/"
target="_blank"><img class="statcounter"
src="http://c.statcounter.com/671400/0/01bacc7f/0/" alt="hit
counter for tumblr"></a></div></noscript>
<!-- End of StatCounter Code for Dreamweaver -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your first opening `<script>` tag is commented out via HTML, but its closing `</script>` tag is not. Not sure that's the problem, but it should be fixed. Also, I see three opening `<table>` tags with **four** closing `</table>` tags. Try properly indenting your code and I'm sure you will find many more errors, and probably the solution to your problem.

Comment: I think you've also removed the `</td>` tag from the end of the slideshow. Add that in after the `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Your cycle plugin script link is broken:

change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much to everyone who responded! I followed your suggestions and its working fine now.